# create a Cascading dropdown on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cascadingdropdown

I try to create some cascasding dropdown on angular with this example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/cascading-dropdown-angular

The first dropdown is ok but the second is not ok.
Could you help me please ?

I would like to put all folders of a user in an array to use them for my second list and later maybe sort the list

Thanks a lot

```
component.html

....

  <div class="">
    <select (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" class="form-control custom-select" >
       <option value="0">--Enfant--</option>
       <option *ngFor="let users of UserDatas.data.User" value= {{users.userId}}>{{users.userName}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
                            
  <div class="">
     <select class="form-control custom-select">
        <option value="0">--Date--</option>
        <option *ngFor="let folder of FolderData " value= {{folder.userId}}>{{folder.data}} 
        </option>
     </select>
  </div>
```

```
component.ts


  UserDatas: any = [];
  FolderData: any = [];

......

  onSelect(userId) {
      for(var i in this.UserDatas.data.User) {
        if(this.UserDatas.data.User[i].userId === userId ){
          this.FolderData.push(this.UserDatas.data.User[i].folders);
        });
          break;
        }
  }
```

```
Userdatas

......

"data":{
        "ent":"MyEnt",
        "User":[
          {
            "userId":"aaaa",
            "userName":"user1",
            "folders":[
                {
                "userId":"aaaa",
                "data":"mydata1"
                },
                {
                "userId":"aaaa",
                "data":"mydata2"
                }
              ],
          },
          {
          "userId":"bbbb",
          "userName":"user2",
          "folders":[
              {
              "userId":"bbbb",
              "data":"mydata11"
              },
              {
              "userId":"bbbb",
              "data":"mydata22"
              }
            ],
          },
    ],

    ........
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: Your html refers to {{folder.mydata}} yet your data only has data, change it to {{folder.data}}

Comment: thanks, but it's juste a write error, it's data and not mydata

Answer (score 0):

Folderdata should be a single level array of objects, like this:

```
[ {...}, {...} ]
```

But this code is turning it into an array of arrays:

```
this.FolderData.push(this.UserDatas.data.User[i].folders)
```

Resulting in this:

```
[ [ {...}, {...} ] ]
```

Comment: ok I understand, but what could I do ? Replace "FolderData: any = [];"  by "FolderData: any;" ? thanks